# История Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, history

Привет,

Я случайно перезатер pipeline в Jenkins, но сначало этого не заметил и сохранил.

Вопсро. Дженкинс где-то хранит историю pipeline? И можно ли как-то откатится на прошлую версию?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: если вы заранее не настраивали на сохранение конфига, то  нет

Comment: Jenkins хранит конфиг в /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/job_name/config.xml , но конфиг файл естествено тоже перезатерся(

Comment: нет. вы можете заранее настроить хранение конфига в VCS.  это делается как раз для таких случае или когда сервер полетел. а поднять нужно быстро все джобы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да востановить без бекапов никак! 
С памяти востановил.

Но что бы в дальнейшем такого не случалось настроил бекап конфигов, джоб и пользователей используя https://gist.github.com/cenkalti/5089392 скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая кнопка в выполненном Item - replay
Там будет код Pipeline